# Getting values of form in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get values form  option value and trying to make them an input field with the help of jQuery but not getting any good results.So initially my markup is just like this

```
 <select name="menus">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
    <option value="e">e</option>
  </select>
```

Now as I have some option like a,b,c,d I will make them select and after selected my markup should be like this

```
    <select name="menus">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
    <option value="e">e</option>
  </select>

<input type="text" value="a" name="a" />a
<input type="text" value="c" name="c" />c
```

Comment: Why are you removing the `name` and `id` from the `select` element?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each($('select option'),function (){

     $('<input type="text" name="'+ $(this).val() +'" />' + $(this).val())
           .appendTo('body');

});
```

or

```
$.each($('select option'),function (){

     $('<input type="text" name="'+ $(this).val() +'" />' + $(this).html())
           .appendTo('body');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try dis

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>
$("select").change(function () {
      var str = "";
      $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            str += $(this).text() + " ";
          });
      $("div").append(text("<input type='text' name='"+str+"' />"));
    })
    .change();
```